# Guessing game where doesn't count the same guess twice

Tags: java, arrays

In my code every wrong guess gets counted, even if they repeat the same guess. But I want to find a way in which it will not count any repeated guesses as a guess, but rather give a message saying that you have already guessed this number and try again.

This is what I have so far (I have no idea how to approach this)

```
public static void main (String[] args)

{
    c = new Console ();

    // Place your program here.  'c' is the output console
    char ynToContinue;
    int maxNumber;
    int minNumber;
    int maxx = c.getHeight ();
    int maxy = c.getWidth ();
    Font titleFont = new Font ("Impact", 0, 45);
    c.setFont (titleFont);
    c.drawString ("LETS PLAY THE GUESSING GAME!!", 50, 180);

    Font font1 = new Font ("Arial", 0, 25);
    c.setFont (font1);
    c.setColor (Color.RED);
    c.drawString ("Press any key to continue", 175, 220);
    char anyKey = c.getChar ();
    c.clear ();
    Font rulesTitle = new Font ("Arial", 0, 20);
    c.setFont (rulesTitle);

    c.drawString ("How To Play:", 5, 25);
    Font subTitle = new Font ("Arial", 0, 18);
    c.setFont (subTitle);
    c.setColor (Color.BLACK);
    c.drawString ("1. The Game will choose a number from the range of your choice.", 5, 45);
    c.drawString ("2. Then you will guess the number.", 5, 65);
    c.drawString ("3. The faster you guess the right number, the higher your score.", 5, 85);
    c.setColor (Color.RED);
    c.drawString ("Press any key to continue", 5, 105);
    anyKey = c.getChar ();
    c.clear ();
    do
    {

        c.println ("Please enter the max number you want to guess");
        maxNumber = c.readInt ();
        c.println ("Pleae enter the minimum number you want to guess");
        minNumber = c.readInt ();
        c.clear ();
    }
    while (maxNumber < minNumber);
    {
    }
    Random generator = new Random ();
    int randomInt;
    randomInt = generator.nextInt ((maxNumber - minNumber) + 1) + minNumber;
    c.drawString (" The Game has chosen a random number within your range", 5, 25);
    c.drawString (" Would you like to guess it? (y/n)", 5, 45);
    do
    {
        do
        {
            ynToContinue = Character.toLowerCase (c.getChar ());
        }
        while (ynToContinue != 'y' && ynToContinue != 'n');
        c.clear ();
        c.print ("GOODBYE");
    }
    while (ynToContinue == 'n');
    {
        c.clear ();
    }
    int guess;
    int guessCount = 0;
    do
    {
        guessCount++;
        c.print ("Enter your guess");
        guess = c.readInt ();
        if (guess > maxNumber || guess < minNumber)
        {
            c.clear ();
            c.println ("That is not withing the range you entered");
            guessCount -= 1;
        }
        else if (guess != randomInt)
        {
            c.clear ();
            c.println ("TryAgain");
        }


    }
    while (guess != randomInt);
    {
        c.clear ();
        c.println ("Congrats");
        c.println ("Your Score is: " + ((maxNumber - minNumber + 1) - guessCount) + " points");


    }


} // main method
} // GuessingGame class
```

Comment: create a set to track the guesses

Comment: Umm. What do you mean, could you please elaborate. PLEASE.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [Set.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) The reason for this is because it does not store duplicate values, so you can check within the set if the user has guessed a value already.

```
Set<Integer> guesses = new TreeSet<>();

do {
    c.print ("Enter your guess");
    guess = c.readInt ();
    if (guesses.contains(guess)) {
        c.clear();
        c.println ("You have already made that guess!");
    } else if (guess > maxNumber || guess < minNumber) {
        c.clear ();
        c.println ("That is not within the range you entered");
    } else {
        guessCount++;
        guesses.add(guess);
        else if (guess != randomInt) {
            c.clear ();
            c.println ("TryAgain");
        }
    }
} while (guess != randomInt);
```

Happy coding! (:

Comment: thank you for replying. But I tried using the code you sent me, and I have never used Set before, so it gave me an error.
Saying that the first "<" is an invalid assignment operator.
The = in the first line is expected to be !=
"new" in the first line is misplaced construct
The last "<" in the first is an invalid name

Ps. I am using ready to program java

Comment: Try `Set<Integer> guesses = new TreeSet<Integer>();`

Comment: Exact same problem. I suppose I should just give up on this until I become a more experienced programmer.